# How does intermodulated fluorescence spectroscopy work?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, spectroscopy, laser-interaction

Via intermodulation of two counter-propagating laser beams, a Doppler-free resonance spectrum of a gaseous sample can be observed in the fluorescence signal (see e.g. [1] [Sorem+Schawlow (1972)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0030-4018(72)90053-3)).

Can someone give a simple explanation of the signal generation mechanism?

[image: Intermodulated fluorescence method for saturation spectroscopy]

(H.J. Foth (1976) "Sättigungsspektroskopie an Molekülen".
Diploma thesis, University of Kaiserslautern)

---

**My thoughts:**

Let $\omega$ be the laser frequency and $\omega_0$ a resonance frequency. Due to Doppler-shift, the two laser beams are absorbed by atoms with a parallel velocity component $v=\pm(\omega-\omega_0)/k$. If $\omega\neq\omega_0$, beams are interacting with different atoms (from different velocity classes) and the fluorescence photons induced by each beam add up independently. Now if $\omega=\omega_0$, both beams interact with the same atoms (at $v=0$), however due to doubled intensity, saturation of the signal is stronger and the combined fluorescence is smaller than before.

According to this, I would expect something like a resonant Lamb-dip on a Doppler-broadened background (similar to pump-probe saturation absorption spectroscopy), which is not what's being observed in the experiments. Also, in my explanation, the beams could be modulated at one frequency (before splitting), which feels pretty fishy.